# Select maximum grouped by years

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering I have the following table

```
WindDirection | WindSpeed | Date
            W |       12  | 17/01/14
          NNW |       20  | 20/02/14
           SE |       15  | 30/04/14
          ENE |       25  | 21/06/15
          NNE |       23  | 10/12/15
          WSW |       8   | 07/01/15
            S |       19  | 05/06/15
```

How can I get the maximum of each year?
I would want to achieve this

```
Year | WindSpeed | WindDirection
2014 |        20 |           NNW
2015 |        25 |           ENE
```

This is my query, it doesn't work, just so you have an idea

```
SELECT CONCAT("20", SUBSTRING(`Date`, -2)) AS `Year`, `WindSpeed`, `WindDirection`
FROM `weather`
WHERE `WindSpeed` = (SELECT MAX(`WindSpeed`) 
                     FROM `weather`)
GROUP BY `Year` DESC
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below query

```
SELECT  B.Year ,
    WindSpeed ,
    A.WindDirection
FROM    weather A
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT YEAR ,
                        MAX(WindSpeed) AS WindSpeed
                 FROM   ( SELECT    YEAR(Date) AS YEAR ,
                                    WindSpeed ,
                                    WindDirection
                          FROM      weather
                        ) A
                 GROUP BY YEAR
               ) b ON A.WindSpeed = b.WindSpeed
                      AND B.YEAR = YEAR(A.Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close.  There are multiple ways to do this, but a simple revision to your query is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT CONCAT('20', RIGHT(`Date`, 2)) AS `Year`, `WindSpeed`, 
`WindDirection`
FROM `weather` w
WHERE w.WindSpeed = (SELECT MAX(w2.WindSpeed) 
                     FROM weather w2
                     WHERE RIGHT(w2.`Date`, 2) = RIGHT(w.`Date`, 2)
                    )
GROUP BY `Year` DESC;
```

Note:  You appear to be storing the date as a string.  You should not be doing that, because MySQL offers proper date/datetime data types.  If it is stored as a `date`, use the `year()` function instead of string manipulation.